# Get max MON-YYYY of full date value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I attach an image as my sample data, what I want to do is to get the max month and year of trans_date and get the sum of its flow_amt.

Example output is

```
AF935906 | 22335.86 | DEC-17
```

[image]

this is my last query but the output was wrong

```
select ltd.acid, sum(ltd.flow_amt) sum_flow_amt, MAX(to_char(ltd.tran_date, 'Mon-YYYY')) as transac_date
    from tbaadm.ltd ltd
    where
      ltd.tran_date <= '31-DEC-17' and ltd.acid = 'AF935906'
```

Thanks

Comment: On a sidenote: `'31-DEC-17'` is not a date literal, but a string. The DBMS will try to convert this to a date and can fail (e.g. when the session is set to another language, in which 'DEC' has no meaning). Use ANSI date literals instead: `DATE '2017-12-31'`. An alternative would be explicit conversion `TO_DATE('31-DEC-17', 'DD-MON-YY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')`.

Comment: As you select `ltd.acid`, I suppose you want this per `ltd.acid` and you forgot the `GROUP BY ltd.acid` when copy-pasting?

Comment: Do you want a result only for `acid = 'AF935906'`? Or is this a test and you want a result per `acid` instead?

Comment: And what Oracle version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are applying `MAX` to a string (`TO_CHAR(...)`. So comparision is alphabetic and 'Jan-2001' is greater than 'Dec-2017', because 'D' comes before 'J' in the alphabet.

So use `MAX` on the date and only then apply the format function `TO_CHAR`.

```
select 
  ltd.acid, 
  sum(ltd.flow_amt) as sum_flow_amt, 
  to_char(max(ltd.tran_date), 'Mon-YYYY') as transac_date
from tbaadm.ltd ltd
where ltd.tran_date <= date '2017-12-31' and ltd.acid = 'AF935906'
group by ltd.acid;
```

**UPDATE:** You say you want the sum only for the last month. So add Oracle's `KEEP LAST` clause to the `SUM`.

```
select 
  ltd.acid, 
  sum(ltd.flow_amt) keep (dense_rank last order by trunc(tran_date, 'month')) as sum_flow_amt, 
  to_char(max(ltd.tran_date), 'Mon-YYYY') as transac_date
from tbaadm.ltd ltd
where ltd.tran_date <= date '2017-12-31' and ltd.acid = 'AF935906'
group by ltd.acid;
```

Comment: I get wrong sum_flow_amt

AF935906 | 294169.75 | Dec-2017

Comment: You get the sum of all `flow_amt` per `acid`. What else is it you want? Only the sum of the last month's `flow_amt`?

Comment: yup the last month DEC-17

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something more like this:

```
select acid, yyyymm, sum_flow_amt
from (select ltd.acid, to_char(ltd.tran_date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm,
             max(tran_date) as max_tran_date,
             sum(ltd.flow_amt) as sum_flow_amt,
             row_number() over (partition by ltd.acid order by to_char(ltd.tran_date, 'YYYY-MM') desc) as seqnum
      from tbaadm.ltd ltd
      where ltd.tran_date <= date '2017-12-31' and ltd.acid = 'AF935906'
      group by ltd.acid, to_char(ltd.tran_date, 'YYYY-MM')
     ) ad
where seqnum = 1;
```

I prefer to have the output in the format YYYY-MM.  If you really want the date in another format, use:

```
select acid, to_char(max_tran_date, 'MMM-YYYY') as mmmyyyy, sum_flow_amt
```